# VLOOKUP match 2 column and output the match value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, inventory

I have 3 columns need to lookup.

Need to find the column RESULT TYPE.

The first 2 column is the inventory and the 3rd column is the result based on the new stocks.

My question is how can I used the VLOOKUP as I match the first 2 column and output its type to the 4th column.

[image]

Comment: `=VLOOKUP($C2, $A$2:$B$6, 2, FALSE)`

Comment: @TimWilkinson is correct, but from your screenshot, it looks as though you're comparing the 4th column (even if the 3rd is empty) so it'd be `=VLOOKUP($D2, $A$2:$B$6, 2, FALSE)` just below RESULT TYPE